# Copying files with specific extension from a list (text file) of directories

Tags: cmd, xcopy

I have a text file with list of certain directories that I want to copy `*.xlsx` files from them to another directory.

This is how the the text file (`list.txt`) is arranged:

```
PT_NAK01, PT_NAK04, PT_NAK05, PT_JAR03
```

What I have so far:

```
@echo off
set main_folder="\\internal.company.com\project folder\"
set my_folder="C:\_M__\files"
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (list.txt) DO (
    xcopy "%main_folder%\%%i" "%my_folder%"
)
```

So the folders that I want to look into would be `\\internal.company.com\project folder\PT_NAK01` etc.

What I don't know is how to pass the specific extension `*.xlsx` to this command.

***Note:*** I haven't used `/S` switch with `xcopy` deliberately because I do not want the files in the sub-directories.

***P.S.*** Solutions in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) or [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) work for me as well.

Comment: Did you try this? `xcopy "%main_folder%\%%i\*.xlsx" "%my_folder%"`

Comment: maybe try `xcopy "%main_folder%\%%i\"*.xlsx "%my_folder%"` . Now the `*.xlsx` is not quoted, and should expand (but I don't use this enough anymore to be sure ;-) ) . Good luck.

Comment: @Masoud It should work like this. But the problem is within your for loop and the comma separated list. Switch on echo and you'll see the output on cmd. It takes the whole list as one folder.

Comment: @MatSnow You're right. I separated the names with carriage return and shellter's comment worked for me. Thanks. Anyhow, if you post an answer I would accept it and this thread will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that made an error in my example was how I set the text file with the folder names. It should be set up with <kbd>carriage return</kbd> as separator instead of `comma-separated` entries.

```
PT_NAK01
PT_NAK04
PT_NAK05
```

etc.

With that, this batch-file (in reference to [MatSnow's and shellter's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920665/batch-copy-certain-files-from-a-list-of-directories/45922377?noredirect=1#comment78800580_45920665)) works fine for the purpose of the question.

```
@echo off
set main_folder="\\internal.company.com\project folder\"
set my_folder="C:\_M__\files"
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (list.txt) DO (
    xcopy "%main_folder%\%%i\*.xlsx" "%my_folder%"
)
```

***Note:*** If you want to type this directly into the command line, you don't need double `%` for the variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin)[shell](/questions/tagged/shell) answer ([bash](/questions/tagged/bash) is an advanced [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) that should be reserved for when standard Posix shell (`/bin/sh`) is insufficient).  Note that slashes are reversed intentionally.

I see the format in your `list.txt` is delimited with commas and whitespace.  I am going to assume that this is literal and the reason none of what you've tried so far works.  Therefore, I am parsing it with the explicit assumption that comma and then space (`,` ) is a delimiter and that there is no way to escape them (e.g. if you have a file named `apples, oranges.txt` then my code would erroneously parse files named `apples` and `oranges.txt`).

```sh
#!/bin/sh
main_folder="${1:-//internal.company.com/project folder}"
my_folder="${2:-c:/_Masoud/files}"
cd "$main_folder" || exit $?
IFS=', ' find $(cat list.txt) -maxdepth 1 -name \*.xlsx |while IFS= read xlsx; do
  mkdir -p "$my_folder/${xlsx%/*}"
  cp -a "$xlsx" "$my_folder/$xlsx"
done
```

I've done some extra work for you to make this more abstract.  `$main_folder` is taken from your first argument (a missing argument will default to `//internal.company.com/project folder`) and `$my_folder` is taken from your second argument (if missing, it defaults to `c:/_Masoud/files`).  Don't forget to quote your command-line arguments if they contain spaces or interpretable characters.

After determining your source and destination, I then try to change directories to the source directory.  If this fails, the script will stop with the same exit code.

Now for the loop.  I've changed the Input Field Separator (`$IFS`) to be the comma and space (`,` ) we talked about earlier and then glued the contents of `list.txt` into its arguments, followed by the requirement of being one level deep (to include `PT_NAK05/foobar/baz.xlsx`, use `-maxdepth 2` or just remove that clause altogether to view the file tree recursively), followed by the requirement of a name matching `*.xlsx` (this is escaped because your shell would otherwise assume you're talking about the local directory).  The output of this is then read into a loop line by line as `$xlsx`.  We recreate the target's parent directory in the new target destination if it's not already present, then we copy the file to that location.  `cp -a` preserves permissions and time stamps.

Comment: Yeah, it's more complicated than it should be, but I wanted to recreate your logic of looping over the items and then copying each one.  I also couldn't get rsync working properly in my tests; theoretically, something like `rsync -a --include '*.xlsx' --exclude '*' "$main_folder" "$my_folder/"` should do the trick, but I've got some part of it wrong.